# Wordpress tag or archive php file customization

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, template-tags

I am not that pro with php but i have good concept and can find my way in cleverly, 
this forum have always put me ahead of the game due to people like you who share as the care,

I have a site that act as a blog site and i have multiple countries scrolling on the top.

```
<a href="http://ca.unitysofts.com/">http://ca.unitysofts.com/</a>
```

What i want to achive is when some one click on say "china" flag, the next page will show all the post from  china  tag. Its working but the twist is, i want to customize

each tag page for each country currently its like this

ca.unitysofts.com/tag/china/

I want to customize this ,so each result first check the tag id, then execute an image of that country flag some wikipedia info of that country ,and then below start the blog roll,

I hope i have explained it, i am sorry for my ignorance , may be the answer is very simple,

thanks

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/9DrDmrHb[link]
this is the php file that genrates the tag file list,

Comment: no code is there in pastebin

Comment: i am sorry , here it is,
http://pastebin.com/cBMYr9c9

Comment: does these tags have featured image set? Means different tags have different images , like china tag have flag of china?

Comment: U need to use tag.php , I think the code you pasted was for category.php                                                   And these countries you are talking about , these are tags and not countries right?

Comment: @amritanshu this theme only have archive.Php that used for cat and tags.

Comment: No these tags don't use feature images. What if I use is_tag() user if

Comment: so you need to use a case structure .  In tag.php use get_the_tag() to get the current tag name / id . Accordingly you can use the images of the flag as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in functions.ph

```
define('IMAGES',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img');
```

where img is the directory where the images for the flags are present

```
<?php
    get_header();
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term = $queried_object->name;


    switch ($term) {
        case "china":
            echo '<img src="  <?php echo IMAGES; ?>/china.jpg">';
            break;
        case "russia":
            echo '<img src="  <?php echo IMAGES; ?>/russia.jpg">';
            break;
        case "india":
            echo '<img src="  <?php echo IMAGES; ?>/india.jpg">';
            break;
    }

    echo '
    <div class="title-head"><h1>'.$term.'</h1></div>

    <div class="blog-fixed">'; 

    $page_layout = page_sidebar_layout();
    switch ($page_layout) {

        case "sidebar-left":
            echo '
        <div id="blog-right">';
            break;

        case "sidebar-full":
            echo '
        <div id="blog-full">';
            break;

        case "sidebar-right":
            echo '
        <div id="blog-left">';
            break;
    }

    if (have_posts())
        while (have_posts()):
            the_post();
            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
            $cover    = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'short-one');
            $no_cover = get_template_directory_uri();
            $author   = get_the_author_meta('ID');
            echo '
            <div class="bl2page-archive">';
                echo '
                <div class="bl2page-cover">';
                if ($image_id) {
                    echo '
                    <a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $cover[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" /></a>';
                } else {
                    echo '
                    <a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src="' . $no_cover . '/images/no-cover/short-one.png" alt="no-cover" /></a>';
                }
                echo '
                    <div class="comment-bubble">
                        <span class="comment-count">' . get_comments_number() . '</span>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            echo '
                <h2 class="bl2page-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title($post->ID) . '</a></h2>
                <div class="bl2page-info">' . get_the_time('F jS, Y') . ' | by <a href="' . get_author_posts_url($author) . '">' . get_the_author() . '</a> </div>';
            echo '' . get_excerpt(230) . '';
            echo '

        </div>';
        endwhile;

    if (function_exists("pagination_wz")) {
        pagination_wz();
    }

    echo '
        </div><!-- end .blog(left&full&right) -->
    ';

    switch ($page_layout) {
        case "sidebar-left":
            echo '
    <div id="sidebar-left">';
            wz_setSection('zone-sidebar');
            if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-page'));
            echo '
    </div><!-- end .sidebar-left -->';
            break;
        case "sidebar-full":
            echo '
    <div id="sidebar-right">';
            wz_setSection('zone-sidebar');
            if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-page'));
            echo '
    </div><!-- end .sidebar-right -->';
            break;
        case "sidebar-right":
            echo '
    <div id="sidebar-right">';
            wz_setSection('zone-sidebar');
            if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-page'));
            echo '
    </div><!-- end .sidebar-right -->';
            break;
    }

    echo '  
    </div><!-- end .blog-fixed -->';

    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Comment: @Rohan Zakie so it did work!!!!  ???

Comment: i am just going to try in few moments, i have seen what you have done, and its clever. 

bundel of thanks u rock.

Comment: i get this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_tag() in /home/unity007/public_html/ca/wp-content/themes/today/archive.php on line 3

Comment: fixed , yup its working, let me play around with it, thanks @amritanshu ur great

Comment: i think get_the_tag may not work. Edited the code. And place that in tag.php and not in archive.php

Comment: @RohanZakie  Please see the updated code

Comment: my theme dont have tag.php , it uses archive.php . but the theme is nice, that why need to get some things customized

Comment: no problem at all you create the file named tag.php and paste that code. There will be no effect on any other thing

Comment: with help of your 2nd fix , thing are working super fine, do check on the site, plus have learned some new stuff, thanks 

learning from the pros are the best,

Comment: i have one last thing to ask, since i have moved to tags from categories as it is more flexible, is there a way that i can show tag name rather then category, when blog roll display all post, e.g
http://s8.postimg.org/eda5gadqd/cat.jpg

Comment: which theme are you using...... can you paste the code from where this code is generating ..Probably a new question would be better, as you need to paste new code